# How to experiment with GitHub Actions without users "watching" the repo getting email notifications

Tags: github, github-actions

On GitHub I get email notifications for repositories I "watch".

I can choose to disable email notifications for a specific repository:

[Watch notification settings per repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RL8u.png)

Or I can do it globally in my settings: [personal settings](https://github.com/settings/notifications)

---

But as a repo owner, can I disable notifications for other users watching my repo?

I plan to build a somewhat more complicated GitHub Action and I suspect it is going to require some trial and error to get it right. I would like to prevent "watchers" getting notifications every time the Action starts & fails or gets aborted while I experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you could do your experiments in a temporary fork of your repo.

Comment: Excellent idea, didn't think of that, thanks!